# Product Page Pricing is 0 after upgrading to Magento 1.9.2.3 from 1.9.1.1

Tags: configurable-product, upgrade, pricing

I just upgraded to Magento 1.9.2.3, and all my configurable products are displaying $0 for pricing. The pricing displays correctly on the catalog page and even when you add-to-cart, just not working on the product page. Not sure how to get this back up and working as I am a rookie to Magento. Please advise. Thanks!

So after some troubleshooting, I've found out that our pricing is working on configurable products only if it doesn't have "in-stock" items. As soon as you add inventory on the simple product, everything goes to Zero on product page.

When I delete this custom file in our theme, pricing works. Anyone able to tell me what is invalid in this file for 1.9.2.3? Would be amazing to get input.

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
$_jsonConfig = $this->getJsonConfig();
$_renderers = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getSortedChildren();
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes)): ?>
    <dl>
        <?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
            <?php
            $_rendered = false;
            foreach ($_renderers as $_rendererName):
                $_renderer = $this->getChild('attr_renderers')->getChild($_rendererName);
                if (method_exists($_renderer, 'shouldRender') && $_renderer->shouldRender($_product, $_attribute, $_jsonConfig)):
                    $_renderer->setProduct($_product);
                    $_renderer->setAttributeObj($_attribute);
                    echo $_renderer->toHtml();
                    $_rendered = true;
                    break;
                endif;
            endforeach;

            if (!$_rendered):
                ?>
                <dt>
                <label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label>
                </dt>
                <dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast)
            { ?> class="last"<?php } ?>>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?><?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select_<?php echo $_product->getId() ?> no-display">
                            <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </dd>
            <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var spConfig_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?> = new Jennyyoo_Product.Config(<?php echo $_jsonConfig ?>);
    </script>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try reindexing your catalog and flushing cache.

If it does not work and you have custom modules try selectivery to disable them by editing XML config files in `app/etc/modules`. Flush cache at every step to see results.

It could also be a template issue, see if it works by setting back the deafult theme.

Comment: I've tried re-indexing and flushing cache, and nothing. However, when I refresh the page, you can see the correct pricing for 1 split second, then they all go to $0. How do i go about disabling the xml files?

Comment: Just setting <active>false</active>, but it seems to me more a template issue, before deactivating custom odules try switching back to deafult theme. Are you using SimpleConfigurableProducts ?

Comment: Hi so I just found out that when I set simple product inventory to "Zero" the configurable product pricing and Made to Order pricing display just fine. But when the item has in-stock inventory for "Simple" product, it reverts all  to $0. Yes we are using SimpleConfigurableProducts. This product works [http://www.jennyyoo.com/index.php/lucy.html]  This one doesn't because it has Inventory [ http://www.jennyyoo.com/index.php/adelle.html]

Comment: Make sure you have the last version of SimpleConfigurableProducts, you may have an aoutdated version.

Comment: Actually, I'm not seeing it listed on our "Magento Connect". So we don't use SimpleConfigurableProducts

Comment: You said you were using it before. Anyway try switching back to default theme for a test.

Comment: Pricing on Default theme works :( .....seems like it's an issue with our simple product.

Comment: No problem, you just need to upgrade your theme to be 1.9.2.3 compliant

Comment: Yep, only problem is I don't know where to start.

Comment: I pasted the configurable.phtml file that is causing the issue. Any clue as to what is triggering the Zero Price on here?

Comment: Try replacing it with the one from base/default. Make a backup of it before.

Comment: Just did that, its working fine now. Just have to figure out how to get our custom Swatches and sizes to display and not the "Drop down" menus. Thanks!

Comment: That's too template specific to solve here, pls mark as solved if you think it is ok.

Comment: Yea, lol I don't expect to get that resolved here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had faced this type of issue recently.I have updated my Magento version to 1.9.2.2, After updated to new version, if i select the price of product, that cost is showing normally fine till here. The main problem is, if i select the any Custom option like color, size That product's price is showing ZERO.

Solution:

First of all,
we need to go to this path

**app/design/your package/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml**

Search for this script

```
price += parseFloat(config[optionId][element.getValue()]);
```

Replace with

```
price += parseFloat(config[optionId][element.getValue()].price);
```

Comment: I don't have this in my code?

Comment: okay , dont worry.  get the congigurable.phtml file from base folder

Comment: I'm also getting this error ReferenceError: spConfig is not defined

Comment: replace once, your configurable.phtml with base/default folder's configurable.phtml

Comment: I did that, and it resolves the pricing issue, but then my product options go back to being "Drop Down" menus instead of images that customers can select. Here's what it's supposed to look like under "Ready to Ship" but you'll notice pricing is all $0.00 [ http://www.jennyyootest.com/index.php/willow-9806.html]

Comment: and this is what it looks like when I replace it with default configurable.phtml [http://www.jennyyoo.com/index.php/willow.html] but you'll notice it goes back to drop-down menu style

Comment: http://jennyyootest.com/index.php/willow-9806.html and http://www.jennyyoo.com/index.php/willow.html